# Boolean Expression Simplification - Issue

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I don't understand where to even begin with this problem. Any helpful tips would be nice.

$(A \lor \lnot B \lor \lnot D) \land (\lnot B \lor C \lor D) \land (B \lor \lnot C \lor \lnot D)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is in [Conjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) (CNF), a *product of sums*.

Probably the easiest way is to create a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) which lists the expression values for all $2^4=16$ input combinations.  Calculate the truth values for the three parts of the expression. The overall expression can only be *true*, if all conjunctive sub-expressions are also *true*.

The analytic way to calculate the [minterms](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-8/minterm-maxterm-solution/) of the expression is to resolve/eliminate the parentheses:

Step 1:

$$(A \lnot B \lor A C \lor AD \lor \lnot B \lor \lnot  B C \lor \lnot B D \lor \lnot B \lnot D \lor C \lnot D) \land (B \lor \lnot C \lor \lnot D)$$

Terms with contradictory literals like $B \lnot B$ result in *false* and are omitted.

Applying the [Absorption Law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsorptionLaw.html), this can be simplified to:

$$(A C \lor AD \lor \lnot B \lor C \lnot D) \land (B \lor \lnot C \lor \lnot D)$$

Step 2:

$$ABC \lor ABD \lor BC \lnot D \lor A \lnot CD \lor  \lnot B \lnot C \lor AC \lnot D \lor  \lnot B \lnot D \lor C \lnot D$$

Absorbing again:

$$ABC \lor ABD \lor BC \lnot D \lor A \lnot CD \lor  \lnot B \lnot C \lor  \lnot B \lnot D \lor C \lnot D$$

To simplify this sum of products, a Karnaugh map helps for expressions with a handful of input variables:

```
             cd
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   00 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
ab    +---+---+---+---+
   11 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   10 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```

A minimized form is

$$C \lnot D \lor \lnot B \lnot C \lor ABD$$

---

To draw the Karnaugh map right a way without involved reasoning, one can negate the literals of the conjunctive clauses to find out which cells of the Karnaugh map are *false/0*. The remaining cells are then *true/1*.

Example: $(A \lor \lnot B \lor \lnot D)$ is *false* for $\lnot A B D$.

Try this method to convince yourself that it directly arrives at the Karnaugh map depicted above.

Comment: Thank you so much